# Change order of tabs in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions

I develop a custom tab to present VSTS build results. Can I change the tabs order, so that my custom tab is the first, thus shown by default?

[image: Move tab to the first position]

The `ms.vss-build-web.build-results-tab` contribution type has an `order` property, which seems to serve my purpose. But I've tried using it with several different values with no effect. The documentation for the property is poor, and I saw some sample mentioning it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Tried it with order property, not working. I submit a user voice here: [vsts build result tab extension order](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/34462900-vsts-build-result-tab-extension-order) that you can vote and follow.